Espacio en una nueva linea despues de un '\n' al imprimir por consola
Capaz es una pregunta medio boba, pero no entiendo por qué me aparece este espacio después de un '\n' cuando imprimo por consola. El código seria el siguiente:
print('Serie random\n','aca tiene espacio')
print('Nueva serie')
print('aca no')

Y este el output de la consola:
Serie random
 aca tiene espacio
Nueva serie
aca no

No entiendo por que el texto 'aca tiene espacio' aparece como si fuera con un ' ' o una especie de sangría al imprimir el texto en la consola.
Ya sea que use command prompt o powershell, el output es el mismo.

Cuando haces print(a, b), Python imprime el prime contenido, que incluye el \n que cambia de línea, luego pone el espacio de separación y después el siguiente contenido.

La documentación oficial siempre debe ser tu primera consulta en estos casos:

print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)
Imprime objects al flujo de texto file, separándolos por sep y
seguidos por end. sep, end, file y flush, si están presentes, deben
ser dados como argumentos por palabra clave.
Todos los argumentos que no son por palabra clave se convierten a
cadenas tal y como str() hace y se escriben al flujo, separados por
sep y seguidos por end. Tanto sep como end deben ser cadenas; también
pueden ser None, lo cual significa que se empleen los valores por
defecto.

El valor por defecto de sep (separador) es ' ', un espacio. Si le pasas más de un objeto a imprimir a print los imprimirá separados por un espacio por defecto.
Si no quieres que se use ningún separador pasa una cadena vacía a sep:
>>> print('Serie random\n', 'aca tiene un espacio', sep=" ")
Serie random
 aca tiene un espacio

>>> print('Serie random\n', 'aca no tiene un espacio', sep="")
Serie random
aca no tiene un espacio

>>> print('Serie random', 'aca no tiene un espacio', sep="\n")
Serie random
aca no tiene un espacio

De la misma forma por defecto end es \n por lo que print por defecto siempre termina con una nueva linea. Si no quieres que eso pase, mas de lo mismo, pasa a end la cadena que quiras con que se termine o una vacía si no quieres nada:
print("Hola", end=" ")
print("mundo", end=".")


Hola mundo.

